# Laravel schedule call function?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a page in my website. Where i can send JSON to servers.
Its manually works good.
I want to automatize it with a combobox where users can select hour of day. When a user set it. Than i want to send Json automatically when time is equal with user selected time.

How can i do it in laravel? 5.1
And most important to set back manually if user do not want to use automatic json send option.

I hope someone can help me. I do not have idea to do that.

```
Thanks!
```

Comment: Please provide more information, and code sample. How your application is arranged. Check the [tour] page to get an idea about how to ask questions on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

To what I understand from your question is that, you want to send data to server when the current system time is equal to the time set by the user, which is assumed to be somewhere in your database.

One possible solution is **cron job**.

Another possible solution is that, you can get the time set by the user every time website loads. And check if the system time matches with the set time **using javascript or any other client side script**. The reason why I personally suggest you this method is because it not only helps user save a lot of data or you from lot of bandwidth but it also improves your website response.

Since this is not a tutorial website, I can't provide you with codes.